# PHP name class from string inside variable

Tags: php, class, object

I'm looking for a way to create a new object with the help of a variable, but instead of referencing it by the variable I want to reference it by the value of the variable.

```
$name = "moduleAjax";
$name = new $name;
```

And instead of doing this,

```
$name->method();
```

I would do this,

```
$moduleAjax->method();
```

I don't have a live example of my code. I've been experimenting a little bit but I can't find a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems rather strange.  Do you mind explaining what situation you would need this in?

Comment: Creating modules for a project. Modules are loaded from folders to minimize the amount of code people have to write in order to make them work and then they can use $moduleName->moduleMethod();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You search for variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

So write:

```
$name = "moduleAjax";
$$name = new $name; // a dollar sign was added to $name
```

Then you can access this newly created instance of the class named `moduleAjax` with the variable `$moduleAjax`.